# Android: Start new activity smaller than the screensize

Tags: android

I have a default activity with just a button

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/openActivity"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
    android:text="Click to open activity" />
```

and a function that opens a new activity:

```
public void openActivity(){
    final Button openActivity = (Button) findViewById(R.id.openActivity);
    openActivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
```

For the second activity I have just a TextView with a custom message:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#a56699"
    tools:context="com.example.tge_00.myapplication.SecondActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewTextToChange"
        android:layout_width="121dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:text="Second Activity" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

that is supposed to be displayed on top of the main activity, smaller than the screens size:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

    int width = dm.widthPixels;
    int height = dm.widthPixels;

    getWindow().setLayout((int)(width*.8), (int)(height*0.6));

}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    this.finish();
    return true;
}
```

But the problem is that the activity from behind should still be visible in the portions where the second activity doesn't cover the screen but those portions are black and I don't know why.

I'm new in Android programming so please be gentle :)

Comment: Just use a DialogFragment, and put all of the code from your second Activity in the Fragment.

Comment: Activities are separate entities . If you want to display both , use two fragments and one activity.

Comment: It's just enough to inherit from `android:Theme.Dialog`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use this theme in your activity.

```
<style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/White</item>
</style>
```